# Rails simple_form_for No route matches, missing [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, form-for, simple-form-for

Straight to the point, a bit confusing here
this is my code

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :main, path: ':master_url' do
    root 'sites#index'
    namespace :dashboard do
        root 'dashboards#index'
      resources :masters
    end
    get "/:action" => 'sites#:action'
  end
  root 'main/sites#index'

end
```

**rake routes**

```
                 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                       Controller#Action
                 main_root GET    /:master_url(.:format)                            main/sites#index
       main_dashboard_root GET    /:master_url/dashboard(.:format)                  main/dashboard/dashboards#index
    main_dashboard_masters GET    /:master_url/dashboard/masters(.:format)          main/dashboard/masters#index
                           POST   /:master_url/dashboard/masters(.:format)          main/dashboard/masters#create
 new_main_dashboard_master GET    /:master_url/dashboard/masters/new(.:format)      main/dashboard/masters#new
edit_main_dashboard_master GET    /:master_url/dashboard/masters/:id/edit(.:format) main/dashboard/masters#edit
     main_dashboard_master GET    /:master_url/dashboard/masters/:id(.:format)      main/dashboard/masters#show
                           PATCH  /:master_url/dashboard/masters/:id(.:format)      main/dashboard/masters#update
                           PUT    /:master_url/dashboard/masters/:id(.:format)      main/dashboard/masters#update
                           DELETE /:master_url/dashboard/masters/:id(.:format)      main/dashboard/masters#destroy
                      main GET    /:master_url/:action(.:format)                    main/sites#:action
                      root GET    /                                                 main/sites#index
```

**main/dashboard/masters_controller.rb**

```
class Main::Dashboard::MastersController < ApplicationController
before_action :all_masters, only: [:index, :create, :update, :destroy]
before_action :set_master, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :show]
before_action :init_master
layout 'main'

respond_to :html, :js

def new
    @master = Master.new
end
def create
    @master = Master.create(conf_params)
end
def edit
end
def update
    @master.update_attributes(conf_params)
end

def destroy
    @master.destroy
end

private
def all_masters
    @masters = Master.all
end
def set_master
    @master = Master.find(params[:id])
end
def conf_params
    params.require(:master).permit(:title,:url)
end
def init_master
    @master_url = Master.find_by_url(params[:master_url])
  end
end
```

this is what i did when partially render **_form_master.html.erb** , which i called on **new.js.erb** and **edit.js.erb**

```
$('#form-master').html("<%= j (render 'form_master', :master => @master) %>");
```

**_form_master.html.erb** contents

```
  <%= simple_form_for [:main, :dashboard, @master], remote: true do |f| %>
                <%= f.input :url, label: 'URL' %>
                <%= f.input :title, label: 'Title' %>
                <%= f.button :submit %>
            <% end %>
```

**PROBLEMS:**

When i called new master, with this

```
<%= link_to new_main_dashboard_master_path, remote: true do %>
```

the page rendered flawlessly, and create master doing good
but when i called edit , with this line

```
<%= link_to :controller=>"masters",:action =>"edit",:id => master do %>
```

[which was my problem earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076136/no-route-matches-missing-required-id-when-using-nested-namespace) , rails returning an error with messages:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"main/dashboard/masters", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :master_url=>#<Master id: 4, url: "test", title: "Test Aja", created_at: "2015-02-02 08:55:07", updated_at: "2015-02-02 08:55:07">} missing required keys: [:id]):
```

i am explicitly render values of master.id and master.title to the page, which is returning correct values.

Q: How do i fix this ? i was trying a couple of times, from changing the locals pass on js.erb, change the @model to just model, still not work

Any help are appreciated, thanks ! :)

Comment: don't we have to pass `:id => master.id`

Comment: More normally: `<%= link_to edit_main_dashboard_master(master) do %>`

Comment: ^ you're missing _path ;) `edit_main_dashboard_master_path(master)`

Comment: calling the edit with `edit_main_dashboard_master_path(master)` make rendering the index, which contain link_to with above line, error : `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"main/dashboard/masters", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :master_url=>#<Master id: 4, url: "aja", title: "Test Aja", created_at: "2015-02-02 08:55:07", updated_at: "2015-02-02 08:55:07">} missing required keys: [:id]):` , that was my problem earlier [in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076136/no-route-matches-missing-required-id-when-using-nested-namespace)

Comment: so i came up with solution changing link_to with: `<%= link_to :controller=>"masters",:action =>"edit",:id => master do %>` or  `link_to edit_main_dashboard_master_path(@master_url.url, master), remote: true do` those two line return a correct path, but break the simple form :| you know im a bit confused @Sontya @ptd @H-man anyway thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Here we have post = Post.find(params[:post_id])

from http://blog.8thcolor.com/en/2011/08/nested-resources-with-independent-views-in-ruby-on-rails/

Don't you have anything like that for your model?
You need an :id of some kind don't you?

This may be out of context but I'm not going to try to reuse your code.
And it may be too simple to try something like 
render plain: params[:someparam].inspect
but it helps me.
http://codefol.io/posts/Deep-Rails-Understanding-HashWithIndifferentAccess-Understanding-the-Params-Hash

Comment: hello @Douglas G. Allen 
thanks for your feedback
firstly, im just using a single model here named Master, which called in every controller, what was the problem here is nested namespace path, thanks for your links im gonna check it asap